# how to create a popup with cookies in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to create a pop up and set cookies expire in 30 sec and displays a  popup when the page loads just once . the problem is my popup it pop ups but my cookies does not work I do not know whats wrong with my code i tired few things but it did not work also i watched few videos.I'm working on this since this morning if you could help me with you are making my day.any help appreciate it in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Latest jQuery Library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Core JS -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Cookie JS for Modal -->
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myModal").modal('show');
 });
 
 
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h3>REGISTER FOR FALL SESSION</h3>
       
            </div>
   
            <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <img src="gym.png" alt="gym_promo" style="width:304px;">
    </div>
    
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <h3> Reserve Your Spot Today </h3>
    <p> EMAIL : <a href="mailto:PLAYATGYM@GMAIL.COM" target="_top">PLAYATGYM@GMAIL.COM </a> </p>
    
    <p>OR CALL :<a href="514-795-4266"> 514-795-4266</a> </p>
    
    
    <script>createCookie();</script>
        
            </div>
   </div>
   </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

  <script>
   function createCookie(name, value) {
   var date = new Date();
   date.setTime(date.getTime()+(30*1000));
   var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();

   document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but I think the way that is integrated into your site will turn away/annoy customers.

Comment: Youre calling createCookie() before its loaded. A short look into your console wouldve revealed that...

Comment: It seems like you are calling `createCookie()` before defining the function have you tried calling it after defining your function?

Comment: Thank you @Jonasw for taking your time to answer my question .i put it before in <body onload="createCookie();"> but still did not work

Comment: @DiegoRosales how bro?

Comment: Cause you may want to pass a name and a value?

Comment: @Jonasw i m not passing any value just a pop up with a message thats it

Answer (score 0):

When you call "createCookie()" you don't pass parameters, and so name and value are undefined, setting the cookie incorrectly.

Also, the script you added to create the cookie will be called when the page loads. Even if the modal isn't shown, it is still loaded, and so the createCookie() function is called. If you want it to be called when the popup pops up, add the line to the jquery you have above:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
    createCookie("name of cookie","value of cookie");
});
```

Comment: thank you @sebitommy123 i put this but still did not work

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
    createCookie("createCookie()",30*1000;");
});

Comment: Did you try debugging and putting a console.log() in the document.ready function to see if it is called.