# How to make a pop up appear just once with js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to create a cookie which expires in 30 sec. If the users refresh the page between this 30 sec, the popup should not pop just when cookie has expired. Users should see it if they refresh the page after 30 sec. My problem is that it keeps popping up, it does not stop. How I can stop that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Latest jQuery Library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Core JS -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Cookie JS for Modal -->
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myModal").modal('show');
  
 });
 
 
</script>
<script>
   function createCookie(name) {
   debugger;
   var date = new Date();
   date.setTime(date.getTime()+(30*1000));
  // alert(date);
   var expires = "; expires="+date.toString();
   document.cookie = name+"="+expires+"; path=/";
//alert(document.cookie);
}
function showbanner()
{
document.write('<div class="container-fluid"><div id="myModal" class="modal fade">    <div class="modal-dialog">        <div class="modal-content"> <div class="modal-header"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> <h3>REGISTER FOR FALL SESSION</h3></div><div class="modal-body"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"> <img src="gym.png" alt="gym_promo" style="width:304px;"></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><h3> Reserve Your Spot Today </h3><p> EMAIL : <a href="mailto:PLAYATGYM@GMAIL.COM" target="_top">PLAYATGYM@GMAIL.COM </a> </p><p>OR CALL :<a href="514-795-4266"> 514-795-4266</a> </p> </div></div></div> </div> </div></div></div>');
 
}
  </script>
  
</head>

<body>
<script>
var ban = document.cookie;

createCookie('banner');
if(ban==""){
showbanner();
}

</script>


  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: might be having to do with the semicolons in commands

Comment: Don't [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46081553/how-to-create-a-popup-with-cookies-in-javascript) your question with a new account.

Comment: @Brian Thank you for taking your time to answer me. No bro i check that but do u think the logic is ok

Comment: its not new account i just repost my questin

Comment: @cdi what do you mean? You responded to [yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46100341) in another repost of this question. I know it won't hold up in court, but the writing with no spaces following periods shows up on [your account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8575482/cdi), and on [afgboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7259887/afgboy).

Comment: @SvenTheSurfer do not you think instead of checking my posts its better to help . anyway brother have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use localStorage over cookies.  Don't worry about expiration, just save the current date on load and check if it is more than 30 seconds than the last load:

```
var lastVisited = window.localStorage.getItem('last visited');
console.log(
  'It has been',
  Date.now() - 5000 > Date.parse(lastVisited) ? 'more' : 'less',
  'than 5 seconds since your last visit.'
)
window.localStorage.setItem('last visited', new Date());
```

Full page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Latest jQuery Library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Core JS -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Cookie JS for Modal -->
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myModal").modal('show');

    });
  </script>
  <script>
    function showBanner(name) {
      var lastVisited = window.localStorage.getItem('last visited');
      if (lastVisited == null || Date.now() - 5000 > Date.parse(lastVisited)) {
        document.write('<div class="container-fluid"><div id="myModal" class="modal fade">    <div class="modal-dialog">        <div class="modal-content"> <div class="modal-header"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> <h3>REGISTER FOR FALL SESSION</h3></div><div class="modal-body"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"> <img src="gym.png" alt="gym_promo" style="width:304px;"></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><h3> Reserve Your Spot Today </h3><p> EMAIL : <a href="mailto:PLAYATGYM@GMAIL.COM" target="_top">PLAYATGYM@GMAIL.COM </a> </p><p>OR CALL :<a href="514-795-4266"> 514-795-4266</a> </p> </div></div></div> </div> </div></div></div>');
      }
      window.localStorage.setItem('last visited', new Date());
    }
    showBanner();
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it still keeps poping up

Comment: @cdi please try the HTML I posted.

Comment: i tired it still does not work bro after 5 sec the pop up does not appear

Comment: @cdi [here](http://jsbin.com/qojaseweka/edit?html,output) is a demo.  click on the `Run with JS` button.  Wait 5 seconds and press again, the modal will pop up again.  Wait less than 5 seconds, you will see no modal pop up.